INSERT OR UPDATE based on table data in single query
I have 2 tables:
Table 1: EnrollmentTransaction
EnrollmentId | TransactionId
-------------+--------------
5            | 1
5            | 2
6            | 3
7            | 2
8            | 3
8            | 2
8            | 1

Table 2: EnrollmentDetail (TransactionId column added newly with default value 1 since it's not null column)
EnrollmentId | ParameterId| TransactionId 
-------------+------------+---------------
5            | 1          | 1
6            | 8          | 1
7            | 9          | 1
7            | 6          | 1
8            | 8          | 1

By referring to Table 1, I would like to insert if there is no entry or update if there is an entry based on EnrollmentId.
For example:
Scenario 1: EnrollmentId = 5 has 2 entries in table 1 whereas, table 2 has only 1 entry and I must insert one more row with values 5, 1, 2 in table 2.
Scenario 2: EnrollmentId = 6 has only 1 entry in table 1 and I need to update with value 6, 8 , 3 in table 2.
Is there any possibility to write a single query to achieve this?
Note: Oracle 19 is the database.
Final result will be like as below. PK of table 2 will be all 3 column EnrollmentId, ParameterId and TransactionId
EnrollmentId | ParameterId| TransactionId 
-------------+------------+---------------
5            | 1          | 1
5            | 1          | 2
6            | 8          | 3
7            | 9          | 2
7            | 6          | 2
8            | 8          | 1
8            | 8          | 2
8            | 8          | 3


It's easier to understand if you give us your expected results as a table rather than describing them. And it seems like you're duplicating data, a bad practice. Perhaps Table 1 needs a simple primary key which table 2 can reference.

What is the logic for assigning parameterId to the new rows? Why does the EnrollmentId/TransactionId pair 5/2 have the parameterId of 1 but the 8/2 and 8/3 rows have a parameterId value f 8?

Use a MERGE statement to combine INSERT and UPDATE:
MERGE INTO EnrollmentDetail d
USING EnrollmentTransaction t
ON (d.enrollmentid = t.enrollmentid AND d.transactionid = t.transactionid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (EnrollmentId, ParameterId, TransactionId)
  VALUES (t.enrollmentid, NULL, t.transactionid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET d.parameterid = d.parameterid -- or whatever you want to update it to.

Note: You do not appear to need the WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ... clause as there is no logic described in the question about what any UPDATE should do; however, I included it in the answer for completeness but it is setting the row to the same value so it could (should) be removed.
Note 2: Your question is not clear what you want paremeterid to be set to in the INSERTed rows; you can replace the NULL value with whatever default you require.
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE EnrollmentTransaction (EnrollmentId, TransactionId) AS
SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE EnrollmentDetail (EnrollmentId, ParameterId, TransactionId) AS
SELECT 5, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 9, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 6, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 8, 1 FROM DUAL;

Then, after the MERGE the table contains:



ENROLLMENTID
PARAMETERID
TRANSACTIONID




5
1
1


6
8
1


7
9
1


7
6
1


8
8
1


7
null
2


8
null
3


5
null
2


6
null
3


8
null
2



fiddle

If you want to use the current parameterId for a given enrollmentId and, if it exists, transactionId then:
MERGE INTO EnrollmentDetail d
USING (
  SELECT t.*,
         ( SELECT d.ParameterId
           FROM   EnrollmentDetail d
           WHERE  d.EnrollmentId = t.EnrollmentId
           ORDER BY CASE 
                    WHEN d.transactionid = t.transactionid
                    THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                    END,
                    d.ParameterId DESC
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY ) AS ParameterId
  FROM   EnrollmentTransaction t
) t
ON (d.enrollmentid = t.enrollmentid AND d.transactionid = t.transactionid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (EnrollmentId, ParameterId, TransactionId)
  VALUES (t.enrollmentid, t.parameterid, t.transactionid)
-- WHEN MATCHED THEN
--   UPDATE
--   SET d.parameterid = d.parameterid -- or whatever you want to update it to.

Which, for the sample data, changes the table to:



ENROLLMENTID
PARAMETERID
TRANSACTIONID




5
1
1


5
1
2


6
8
1


6
8
3


7
6
1


7
9
1


7
9
2


8
8
1


8
8
2


8
8
3



fiddle

Yes, exactly I want like this. PK will be all 3 columns.  but how to retain the parameterId value instead adding NULL?

@Seegel Updated

Got it, one more thing. If I want to retain more column values from Table 2 along with ParameterId, what would be the query to return multiple column values? I am not showing it in my question posted to avoid more confusion.  as of now, the query returns a single column value. I tried to modify but nothing helped.

@Seegel You are inserting extra rows into EnrollmentDetail (Table 2) and you do not need to modify any of the existing data so the existing query should work as it is (fiddle shows it retaining the existing columns). If you want something different then ask a new question and provide a [MRE] with the details of the input and expected output data.

I got almost what I need to achieve from your query. The only thing I need is, while inserting a new row, I need to retain other values too instead NULL values. like A, B, C and D column value from your https://dbfiddle.uk/pSr0Pk52

@Seegel Something like fiddle. Anything else, you really should ask a new question

I posted question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78727624/insert-and-update-the-values-into-the-table-based-on-condition

The main problem - that you do not address - in the question is the missing definition of the unique match between your two tables.
It seems that the EnrollmentTransaction has the PK of (EnrollmentId, TransactionId) and the EnrollmentDetail has no PK, possible the combination of (EnrollmentId, ParameterId) is unique.
So if you have two rows in the main table and one in the detail table, how could you decide with transactionId from the main table matches and which not?
Assuming this, I'll use the row_number trick to generate surrogate PK to enable the unique outer join on them.
with et as (
select 
et.*,
row_number() over (partition by EnrollmentId order by TransactionId) rn
from EnrollmentTransaction et),
ed as (
select 
ed.*,
row_number() over (partition by EnrollmentId order by ParameterId) rn
from EnrollmentDetail ed)
select et.EnrollmentId, et.TransactionId, ed.ParameterId
from et
left outer join ed
on et.EnrollmentId = ed.EnrollmentId and et.rn = ed.rn
order by 1,2
;

ENROLLMENTID TRANSACTIONID PARAMETERID
------------ ------------- -----------
           5             1           1
           5             2            
           6             3           8
           7             2           6
           8             1           8
           8             2            
           8             3   

What you see is actually the new version of the EnrollmentDetail table and as I assume you are doing some sort of one time cleaning / redesign of the table, I'd recommend to simple
re-create the table with create table as using this query instead of using a MERGE.
You may want to add a default value of ParameterId and do not forget to add PK (EnrollmentId, TransactionId) on both tables to fix the design for future.
